# C# - Menustrip- Check if Parent exists and get the reference to them

Tags: c#, dynamic, items, menustrip

First of all Thanks for your Time! I hope you can help me =/

I have a MenuStrip where i want to add items dynamically.

What i want to do :
If a Partent with exactly the same name already exists the Childs should be add to this parent instead creating a new Parent(MenuStripItem) with the same name.

My Code does currently checks if the parent already exists (which works fine) but the problem is i cant get the reference to this parent -> firstItem=var doesnt work -> cant convert ToolStripItem to ToolStripMenuItem... and changing the "firstItem" to ToolStripItem gives me an Error because i cant use  "firstItem.DropDownItems.Add(withChild);" anymore to add a Child later on...

```
        private void AddNewMenuStrips(string [,] NewMenuStripInfo)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem firstItem; 
         bool alreadyexists = false;
         string someItem = "Settings"; // the parent im looking for
        var items = menuStrip2.Items.Find(someItem+"ToolStripMenuItem",false); //here it checks if parent already exists. Which Works but i cant get the reference of the parent to  "firstItem"

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FOUND"+item.Name);
            firstItem = var; // ERROR cant convert ToolStripItem to ToolStripMenuItem   
            alreadyexists=true;                             
        }

        if (alreadyexists == false) { firstItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(someItem); }  
   }
```

THANKS in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToolStripMenuItem` is a class which represents top level menu items and derives (not directly) from `ToolStripItem`.

Therefore to retrieve the parent menu item you can use a cast:

```
foreach (var item in parents)
{
    MessageBox.Show("FOUND" + item.Name);
    firstItem = item as ToolStripMenuItem;
    alreadyexists = true;
    // break;
}
```